# Sequel validations in concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sequel, sequel-gem

I have a Sequel model like this:

```
class User < Sequel::Model
  include Notificatable

  def validate
    super
    validates_presence [:email]
  end
end

# concerns/notificatable.rb
module Notificatable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      def validate
        super
        validates_presence [:phone]
      end
    end
end
```

And here I got a problem: `Notificatable` validate method overrides the same method in the `User` model. So there is no `:name` validations.

How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use a concern?  Simple ruby module inclusion works for what you want:

```
class User < Sequel::Model
  include Notificatable

  def validate
    super
    validates_presence [:email]
  end
end

# concerns/notificatable.rb
module Notificatable
  def validate
    super
    validates_presence [:phone]
  end
end
```

Comment: Because I need to add some more stuffs, like Sequel plugins and relations.

Comment: Then make Notificatable a Sequel plugin instead of a concern.

Comment: Ok, I will try to find some info about creating of Sequle plugins. Thanks!